# When do we put adjectives before or after nouns?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, postpositive-adjectives

My question is: when do we put adjectives before nouns, and when do we put adjective after nouns? Because sometimes, I heard people put adjectives before nouns and sometimes after.

Comment: You mentioned that you heard people. Would you mind sharing what you heard [from them]? It would help in providing an explanation.

Comment: There's a thorough article addressing this at the given link (the right thing to do would be for me to summarise it and post it as an answer with a link to the article, but I don't have time right now - someone else please feel free to do so) http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjective-phrases-position

Answer (score 4):

1. Adjectives usually go before nouns in English.
2. Adjectives can be a *subject complement*, in which case they will follow a linking verb as described below.  The following is an excerpt from [here](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subjectcomplement.htm) that explains:

   > The following verbs are true linking verbs: any form of the verb be
   >   [am, is, are, was, were, has been, are being, might have been, etc.],
   >   become, and seem. These true linking verbs are always linking verbs.
   >
   > Then you have a list of verbs that can be linking or action: appear,
   >   feel, grow, look, prove, remain, smell, sound, taste, and turn. If you
   >   can substitute any of the verbs on this second list with an equal sign
   >   [=] and the sentence still makes sense, the verb is almost always
   >   linking.
3. However, there are many cases where adjectives can follow the noun.  The General Uses section in the Wikipedia article [Postpositive Adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective) explains it comprehensively.

   As a rough guide though, generally putting an adjective after the noun *[noun] X* is the equivalent to saying *[noun] that is X*

   Following the examples from the Wikipedia site:

   > Every star visible is named after a famous astronomer = Every star that is visible is named after a famous astronomer.
   >
   > I'm here to find the people responsible = I'm here to find the people that are responsible.
   >
   > we need a box bigger than that = we need a box that is bigger than that

   There are also a number of set phrases that could in a way be considered compound words, and other cases detailed in the article.